# Pandas: find interval distance from N consecutive to M consecutive

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## TLDR version:

I have a column like below,

```
[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]
# There is the probability that has more sequences, like 4, 5, 6, 7, 8...
```

I need a function that has parameters n,m, if I use
n=2, m=3,
I will get a distance between 2 and 3, and then final result after the group could be :

```
[6, 9]
```

## Detailed version

Here is the test case. And I'm writing a function that will give n,m then generate a list of distances between each consecutive. Currently, this function can only work with one parameter `N` (which is the distance from N consecutive to another N consecutive). I want to make some changes to this function to make it accept `M`.

```py
dummy = [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': dummy})
```

What I write currently,

```py
def get_N_seq_stat(df, N=2, M=3):
    df["c1"] = (
        df.groupby(df.a.ne(df.a.shift()).cumsum())["a"]
        .transform("size")
        .where(df.a.eq(1), 0)
    )
    df["c2"] = np.where(df.c1.ne(N) , 1, 0)
    df["c3"] = df["c2"].ne(df["c2"].shift()).cumsum()

    result = df.loc[df["c2"] == 1].groupby("c3")["c2"].count().tolist()

    # if last N rows are not consequence shouldn't add last.
    if not (df["c1"].tail(N) == N).all():
        del result[-1]
    if not (df["c1"].head(N) == N).all():
        del result[0]
    return result
```

if I set N=2, M=3 ( from 2 consecutive to 3 consecutive), Then the ideal value return from this would be [6,9] because below.

```
dummy = [1,1,**0,0,0,1,1,0,**1,1,1,0,0,1,1,**0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,**1,1,1]
```

Currently, if I set N =2, the return list would be [3, 6, 4] that because

```
dummy = [1,1,**0,0,0,**1,1,**0,1,1,1,0,0,**1,1,**0,0,0,0,**1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify your code this way:

```
def get_N_seq_stat(df, N=2, M=3, debug=False):
    # get number of consecutive 1s
    c1 = (
        df.groupby(df.a.ne(df.a.shift()).cumsum())["a"]
        .transform("size")
        .where(df.a.eq(1), 0)
    )

    # find stretches between N and M
    m1 = c1.eq(N)
    m2 = c1.eq(M)
    c2 = pd.Series(np.select([m1.shift()&~m1, m2], [True, False], np.nan),
                   index=df.index).ffill().eq(1)

    # debug mode to understand how this works
    if debug:
        return df.assign(c1=c1, c2=c2,
                          length=c2[c2].groupby(c2.ne(c2.shift()).cumsum())
                                       .transform('size')
                        )

    # get the length of the stretches
    return c2[c2].groupby(c2.ne(c2.shift()).cumsum()).size().to_list()

get_N_seq_stat(df, N=2, M=3)
```

Output: `[6, 9]`

Intermediate `c1`, `c2`, and length:

```
get_N_seq_stat(df, N=2, M=3, debug=True)

    a  c1     c2  length
0   1   2  False     NaN
1   1   2  False     NaN
2   0   0   True     6.0
3   0   0   True     6.0
4   0   0   True     6.0
5   1   2   True     6.0
6   1   2   True     6.0
7   0   0   True     6.0
8   1   3  False     NaN
9   1   3  False     NaN
10  1   3  False     NaN
11  0   0  False     NaN
12  0   0  False     NaN
13  1   2  False     NaN
14  1   2  False     NaN
15  0   0   True     9.0
16  0   0   True     9.0
17  0   0   True     9.0
18  0   0   True     9.0
19  1   2   True     9.0
20  1   2   True     9.0
21  0   0   True     9.0
22  0   0   True     9.0
23  0   0   True     9.0
24  1   3  False     NaN
25  1   3  False     NaN
26  1   3  False     NaN
```